# RESTful Application edit is not reflected on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat

I followed [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm) tutorial and I was able to successfully get the same result as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Mahesh</name>
        <profession>Teacher</profession>
    </user>
</users>
```

For testing purposes I modified the UserDao.java class with following code:

```
        User user = new User(1, "Maheshooo", "TeacherDDD"); 
        User user2 = new User(2, "John", "Brown"); 
        userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
        userList.add(user); 
        userList.add(user2); 
        saveUserList(userList);
```

I exported the war file again, then I restarted tomcat server with the new war file but I still get the very same response Mahesh and Teacher like above without 2nd user, I would expect at least the first user to change to Maheshooo and TeacherDDD.

Also in this example I would like to use PUT as well, could you explain how can I add it too?

I am using Win 7, Eclipse Neon, Java 1.8, tomcat 8.5 and jersey 2.25.1. I would be glad if you can give a hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because :

```
     File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
     if (!file.exists()) { 
        User user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Teacher"); 
        userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
        userList.add(user); 
        saveUserList(userList); 
     }else{ 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
        userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject(); 
        ois.close(); 
     }
```

As par the code file is write at fist time and the it will not go for write it again.
So you will not get affect until you delete `Users.dat` file.

Comment: But I open the Users.dat and see my new entries and also when the war file is unzipped.

Comment: Just look at the code, do you think it is possible to write file if it is already exist, there is already condition that go for the write only if not exist.

Comment: I changed the file name and it worked but when I open Users.dat file generated in Eclipse workspace I really see the new entries... maybe on tomcat it is created somewhere too...

Comment: Indeed, it was also created in tomcat bin directory, thanks!